# Issue installing SIP 4.18 on mac OS X El Capitan

Tags: pyqt5

I am trying to install sip 4.18 and PYQt5. i have tried sudo but doesn't work. This is the error I am getting. Please help!!!

waheed$ sudo make install
Password:
cp -f sip /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/sip
cp: /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/sip: Operation not permitted
make[1]: *** [install] Error 1
make: *** [install] Error 2

Answer (score 0):

I had exactly the same issue on Sierra.

This article explains the issue: http://arstechnica.com/apple/2015/09/os-x-10-11-el-capitan-the-ars-technica-review/8/#h1

**Solution:**

1. You have to reboot in Recovery Mode (cmd+R while booting)
2. Open a terminal in Utilities
3. Disable the System Integrity Protection with this command: csrutil disable
4. Reboot

You can of course enable it again later.